# How to make mongoose schema property of type (another) schema required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this mongoose post schema.

In validation, is the `author` with type `UserSchema`, `required: true` by default or false?

**snippet 1**

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  author: UserSchema,
  ...
});
```

I want to have something like this where the `author` with type `UserSchema` is `required: false`

**snippet 2**

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: UserSchema,
    required: false
  }
});
```

Is there any other way to do something like this, schema property type another schema to be required true or false? --new to mongoose

Comment: btw is this possible anyone?

Comment: I think you may need to create a custom schema type to do that: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html

Answer (score 1):

This is very very old but I was working on something similar and I tested it myself and this indeed does work!